Round robin tournament + constraints
I am organizing a backyard games tournament where I have 10 teams.
I need to create a schedule where:

Each team plays another team exactly once
Teams cannot play themselves
Each team must play each backyard game exactly one

I'm trying to solve:

How many rounds will there be?
How many games do I need to buy?

The round robin part isn't difficult to solve, and I tried integrating it with a latin square, but it isn't quite right.
Are there other algorithms I should be looking at?

so, there's 9 teams, and all of them need to play a certain 1v1 game exactly once? That doesn't add up. It can work for an even number of teams, or if one team sits out each game

@user2661923 for scheduling the round-robin to satisfy the first constraint, the ghost team works. But the problem remains, that "playing the ghost team" does not constitute playing that game.

Unless, I suppose, the ghost team can be an actual team (say, the adults at a kids' party) who can play the game but don't count in the tournament

@angelica I deleted my comment after I saw that your first comment had included the possibility of one team sitting out each round.

@Angelica you are right, that was an oversight. 10 teams would probably a lot easier!

As I noted in the comment, it is not possible for an odd number of teams to play a 2-team game once each. There are four solutions to this:

Each game is played twice by one team
Each game is skipped by one team
You scrounge up enough players for 10 teams
You redistribute players (or see if some don't want to play) into 8 teams

For cases (2), (3), and (4), this problem is quite hard, but solved for small $n$ for the game of Bridge, in what is called the Howell movement. For case (1), Bridge doesn't help, since repeating a game implies that one side will already know all the cards.
Listed below are some schedules which should work for each of the latter three options. Note that a "pair" is equivalent to your teams, and a "board" is equivalent to one of your games. "Tables" have no particular meaning. A team with no opponent in a round sits out for that round.
Case (2): 9 teams, one sit-out per game

Case (3): 10 teams

Case (4): 8 teams

Note that for cases (2) and (3), there are 9 rounds and 9 games required. For case (4), 7 rounds and 7 games are required.
Howell movements retrieved from here.

Edit: If there is an additional team of players who wish to play the games, but not be included in the tournament, then the requirements may be met exactly by adapting case (2) to have the extra team play an "exhibition match" with the sit-out.
